# Unity3d freezes when you get a phone call while recording video

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have a problem with Google Play Services new video recording in Unity on Android 7.0.

When the user gets a phone call while recording video, the video will stop recording, then after the phone call is completed the screen will be black until the user kills the game.

For whatever reason this is happening only if user was authenticated in the game, if not it's all cool.

I do have a source code I could share (privately), please contact me if needed.

Using:

- Google Play SDK 10.0.1
- Unity 5.4.3p2
- Google Play for unity 0.9.35

How to reproduce:

1. Authenticate with C# (important)
2. Create API client using native Java library and start recording (plugin for Unity)
3. Start the recording
4. Initiate a phone call to the phone, accept it and then finish it
5. Notice the screen is now black and you have to kill the game.

   ```
   // C# code
   GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((bool success) =>
   {
   Debug.LogWarning("LOGGED IN VIA AUTHENTICATE");
   });

   // Java Native code
   GoogleApiClient client = GoogleApiClient.Builder(m_activity).addApi(Games.API).
   addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES).
   build();

   Intent overlay=  Games.Videos.getCaptureOverlayIntent(client);
   this.startActivityForResult(overlay, 777);
   ```

Again, the weird thing is that when the game is not using the `Authenticate()` call it is all fine, when it is there is a soft lock. Not sure if maybe due to GPGS working with both C# and Java native code as C# GPGS does not support screen recording yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit; the "#" puts things in a very large font, which may come across as "shoiuting". All in all, however, this is an interesting question, with a code example and steps to reproduce. Voting up, hope you'll get an answer!